# How can i set the selected value of a dropdown list within an MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I create the dropdown list within an mvc view as follows

```
<select id="SupplierID" name="SupplierID" class="form-control">
        <option value="-1">Please choose...</option>
        @foreach (demo.Suppliers s in Suppliers)
           {
              <option value="@s.SupplierID">@s.SupplierName</option>
           }
</select>
```

Supposing i have a variable returned from the controller with the selected SupplierID, can i set the selected value with it?

P.S. I do not want to use `Html.DropDownList` or `Html.DropDownListFor` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your selected value located in `demo.SupplierID` then:

```
<option value="@s.SupplierID" @(s.SupplierID==demo.SupplierID?"selected":"")>@s.SupplierName</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option selected="selected">
//Here in foreach you can pass selected  SupplierID from Controller
</option>
```

But I like to suggest if you are using MVC framework then best way to do this is use  model for specific class and helper method  i.e. DropdownListFor.